# Issue running firefox built from source (on Ubuntu 9.10)

Tags: linux, firefox, build

The title of the question sums it up pretty well.  I've downloaded the source for firefox 3.6 and built it (no errors), but when I try to run it, I get a warning that says:

```
(firefox-bin:2857): GLib-WARNING **: g_set_prgname() called multiple times
```

I'm not sure what to try now.  Any suggestions?  Or even a better place to ask this question?

*EDIT - It's not that I only get a warning, that wouldn't bother me.  The problem is that the warning is the only thing that ever happens (no firefox windows show up or anything).  When I run it from the terminal, that warning shows up twice and then nothing else happens (it just hangs and I have to Ctrl-C it).

Answer (score 1):

Bug in Glib introduced while trying to fix https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=563627 and, as discussed in that bug, later backed out because of the issue you're seeing.  The warning will go away once you get a newer version of Glib.

Answer (score -1):

Quick comments:

1. It's a warning, not an error. This is not a problem but looks like the library wanted to be used differently. So why worry?
2. Why did you build it from source?  If you want newer packages, I usuaully start with Debian sources and turn those into local packages -- as this incorporates whatever the package maintainers deemed worthy and will be closer to the package you will get at the next Ubuntu upgrade.

Comment: I built it from source b/c I'm interested in learning how it works.  I wanted to put my own debug info in the src after I rebuild it to see which paths it goes down.

Comment: Sure, but you can study that in the package built process too. Plus, it gives you both normal ("release") and debug versions -- just install the corresponding foo-dbg package (which many but not all packages 'foo' provide) and you have debugging symbols.

Comment: These comments should be just that, `comments` not an answer.